# Fail to read a self defined data type

Tags: haskell, typeclass, deriving

```
data MyNum = One
           | Two
           | Three
           deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I just define `MyNum` with constructor `One`, `Two` and `Three`.

> *Main> :t One
>
> One :: MyNum

But ghci produces errors when I add `x = read("One")::MyNum` to my program:

> No instance for (Read MyNum) arising from a use of ‘read’
>
> In the expression: read ("One") :: MyNum
>
> In an equation for ‘x’: x = read ("One") :: MyNum

Why couldn't I `read` it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to derive `Read` in definition of `MyNum`:

```
data MyNum = One
           | Two
           | Three
           deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

x = read("One")::MyNum
```

> *Main> x
>
> One